# How do I build MWDumper from source?

Tags: java, build, compilation, makefile

Java newbie here. I'm trying to run the latest version of [MWDumper](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aMWDumper), which is a command-line utility that imports wiki databases. The page said I should build it from its [source](http://svn.wikimedia.org/svnroot/mediawiki/trunk/mwdumper/). I've downloaded the source-code. They've got a makefile and a build.xml. How do I build this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install ANT and run ANT in the folder containing the build.xml.

If you're on linux or mac it's pretty easy - you just [package manager name here] install ant;
You then just cd to the appropriate folder and type in ant. It should build your app.

You also need to make sure that you have the Java Development Kit installed for the ANT to use. Ant doesn't actually do any compiling, it's just a tool that reads build instructions and calls various applications and compilers to output the end executable (or similar product).

You should be able to install 'jdk' from your package manager, or from their site (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

If you're on Windows, you can install the JDK from the same link, and you can follow the following link as a guide to install ant for windows: http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html

Don't forget to add the path to ant to your environment 'PATH' variable! :) (more details in the link above)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/).

```
cd <dir>
ant <target>
```

Also you can use [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

```
cd <dir>
mvn install
```

Comment: Can you be specific? What's target?

Comment: try just "ant". There is default target in build.xml - jar.

Comment: So do I type ... cd "C:\JavaDir\"

Comment: Open cmd. Type "cd C:\project_dir" (path to your project dir.). Then type "ant".